# Show flag in questions lists when close votes have been made

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, moderation

Similar to: [Show possible duplicates in the main post before it's closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1383/show-possible-duplicates-in-the-main-post-before-its-closed)

In order to close duplicate and other problem questions more quickly. If a question has a close vote, a small icon could be shown in the list view, which will let the other mods know that that question may need to be closed.

This will be helpful in the case where *someone* has determined that a question is a dupe, but not enough other mods notice.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, this would be mostly taken care of by [Show possible duplicates in the main post before it’s closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1383/show-possible-duplicates-in-the-main-post-before-its-closed), provided the links were added to the top of the question such that they showed up in the preview.

This is how we did it prior to the implementation of the current system for linking duplicate questions, and it seemed to work pretty well...

Comment: Yes, that's a good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I like what your question title states, but it seems like you deviate from that a bit in the main section of the post...

I think a flag or some kind of icon that could be shown to suggest that a question has received a close vote would be very beneficial.  Folks with the rep may actually get to closing these questions quicker which improves overall content on the site...

Comment: I think the confusion was with my point on the similarity to 'flag to moderator'. I changed the post accordingly.

Comment: Great!  Still completely love the idea!