# Show the reason given for a close vote before the question gets closed

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, close-reasons, moderation

If a question gets votes to close but no answer or comment stating the reason for the vote, the OP has no way of knowing if editing would solve the problem.

Show to the asker the reasons (but not who voted) given for a vote to close so they can attempt to correct the problem without having to resort to begging for a reopen or reposting an edited version and risk being called a duplicate.

Comment: New dicussion originated from this question: [Add close reason as a comment after Vote to Close](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247688/245360).

Comment: related: [Tell answer-author when the question is being voted to close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322503/165773)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The OP of a question shouldn't have to cast a vote to close his question just to see how many close votes it got and why. There ought to be another way for the OP to get that info.

Answer (score 10):

There's one specific close reason where i think this would be very, very useful:

#### [Show possible duplicates in the main post before it’s closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1383/show-possible-duplicates-in-the-main-post-before-its-closed)

Right now, i see an awful lot of duplicates left un-closed, prompting duplicate answers / bifurcated answer sets... and i wonder if it isn't that they're just not visible enough to those who could be closing them.

Answer (score 3):

This is already implemeted, if you click on close you see what other people voted

Comment: But can you view this if you have less than 3k rep?  The proposal is to allow you to do so on your own questions.

Comment: You already can, I tested on a question of mine here and I don't have 3000 rep

Comment: How is a new user (the type of users most lickly to have their question closes) ment to know about this?

Comment: As a user, I'm not going to click on close because that means I want to close my own question.  'Close' means "Please close this question" , not "Let me see details about the close vote and possibly vote to close it".  How is a user supposed to know that function exists?

Comment: @Juan: I'll take your word for it, then.  +1

Answer (score 2):

Usually if nobody comments on how to fix it, it's FUBAR.

But, I think showing the vote totals would be beneficial to the OP. Or it may make them feel unloved when they see the amount of stuff that has at least one close vote. Either way, it's a win, and I'm for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the close link, it shows you how many votes each current option has.

However, I'm not sure that you can tell what's going on if you don't have enough rep to vote to close yourself...

Comment: If it's your question you can

Comment: @Juan: Only > 250 rep.

Comment: Jon Skeet spends so little time under 3k rep that he has forgot what it's like to be mortal.

Comment: I think Jeff should made a small change for new sites in the trilogy, whereby Skeet gets a -1000 point bonus for associating his account, just to make things more sporting.

Answer (score 0):

If there are only one or two close votes and no comments, don't worry about.  We are a community of people with different views.  It takes [5 votes to close a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes), so one or two is not cause for concern. Some of the community express opinions about past events by down voting new questions. They know the question is unlikely to be closed, they just like to throw stones.

If you see 3 or more close votes and no comments, check the sites meta and see if there are any recent (today or the last month) conversations about your question or topic.

There are a couple of existing answers addressing, how to see what the close votes are for. As for the other part;

> the OP has no way of knowing if editing would solve the problem.

Every site has a help page [How do I ask a good question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) If that is not sufficient to help the OP get on track, they can post a comment asking for why it is getting close and/or down votes, on most sites I visit regularly someone will normally offer advice like "I did not vote, but..."

Occasionally a question is posted by a new user on Beta sites, where the community is still working towards consensus. Questions may be closed and re-opened without the OP making any changes, in these cases there is normally comments under the question and/or a meta post about the question or topic.

Comment: in small communities, it can take more than a day to get a question closed. Waiting that much time to provide the first feedback  to the OP seems too much. Showing some indicator [like when a duplicate is suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250981/209901) can close the loop quite faster.

Comment: @fedorqui I don't understand your comment, you are asking for an indicator of proposed dupe, when it already exists?

Comment: No: I am suggesting to have an indicator (like the OP says) telling that there are some close votes, the same way we have an indicator when there are votes for duplicates.

Comment: @fedorqui but some close vote does not mean the question will be closed, nor is it conclusive that the post needs work.  One or two people don't like it and did not leave a comment. Are there any stats that show a relationship to a close vote and actually getting closed?

Comment: Agreed. Sometimes it is noise, but in many others is a good indicator of what improvements could be done to the post. Unfortunately, I do not have stats, but I recall many situations in a small site I moderate and a bigger one I visit often.

Comment: This makes me think that there could be some logic here to display the indicator: if a gold badge holder of a tag involved votes to close as "unclear", show it; if two or more users do so, show it.

Comment: @fedorqui I am not sure your "gold badge holder" is a viable measure.  I think (but don't know) that collecting enough rep to close vote, also usually includes enough activity to get a gold badge or two.

Comment: Sorry if my was wording was not very correct, but what I meant is "gold badge holder of a tag involved". That is, someone who owns a tag gold badge on one of the tags of the question.

Comment: @fedorqui maybe you should write an answer describing what you are thinking?