# Search for vote-to-close

Tags: feature-request, search

I would like to search for vote-to-close by number of votes, especially for posts that I have voted to close. For less popular tags, it can be some time before any further action is taken, if any action is taken at all.

If this question relates too closely [Make "close votes" appear in recent activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11188/make-close-votes-appear-in-recent-activity), I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gain the facility to see the number of close votes per question when you reach 10k rep, this is part of the tools functions you gain access to.

When you gain access to the moderator tools, you are able to view a list of questions, ranked by the number of close votes, so you can see which questions have the most close votes. You are also able to view lists of most voted questions, most downvoted questions etc.

Comment: Can you explain a little more? I can already see the number of close votes if I am viewing a question, but I wish to find questions with close votes, particularly within the ms-access tag or voted by me, because ms-access is not mainstream stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You're at roughly 7.5k rep at the time I am writing this. When you get to 10k, you have access to a tools menu. The tools (among other things) will show you questions with the most pending close votes.

Comment: So not quite what I was thinking of it seems, but I must wait quite a while to find out :)