# Add a "voted to close" activity event somewhere on the user profile page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, vote-to-close, recent-activity

Often when I vote to close, I want to go back and check the comments on the question, to see if it's been improved, to comment further, or to answer the question.

It would be helpful to add a bit of a trail so I can find those questions again. I'm suggesting adding an event to the Activity page on the user profile, because this is the logical spot for the given action.

I realize the Activity page is public, but I don't see why this content couldn't be added only for the currently logged-in user.

An alternative would be to add a new tab on the user profile page that only lists current-user content, and is not shown publicly. I'm sure there are other events, data, or statistics that could be shown here as well, so I'm certain a new tab like this wouldn't be underutilized.

---

One thing that could be done instead of this is to always add a comment stating why I voted to close. This works well enough, but only some of the time -- for example, if there is already a vote to close as a duplicate and a comment with a link to that duplicate, I'm not going to add a comment myself if I have nothing to add aside from a close vote.

Another way to do it would be to favourite the question. This only works well to a point since questions that get voted to close don't necessarily end up being downvoted (i.e., for my "closed favourites," I couldn't just look at the last page of my favourites).

---

Related: Jon Skeet [suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11188/make-close-votes-appear-in-recent-activity) that votes to close on your own questions be shown in the Recent Activity area, which is not what I'm requesting here.

Comment: Captain Skeet's suggestion is the same as yours, man. One begets the other. Close votes given and received should both be visible. Note my accepted answer to his suggestion.

Comment: Actually not a duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11188/make-close-votes-appear-in-recent-activity - can I rescind my close vote please. The linked question is from the poster's point of view, not the closer's. Will vote to re-open if it does get closed.

Comment: @ChrisF: see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11188/make-close-votes-appear-in-recent-activity/11190#11190

Comment: @Urdnot You can't vote to close a question as a duplicate of an answer. It would be better to edit http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11188/make-close-votes-appear-in-recent-activity/11190#11190 so that it includes this idea. Until it does, this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Sure it is. You're awfully wrong.

Comment: Which is not to say I don't support it, because [I definitely do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94816/revisiting-recording-close-reopen-votes-in-the-profile) we just probably need to drum up support (e.g., with a bounty) on one of the older proposals.

Comment: @jonsca, it's an accurate dupe flag, I think?  I searched for "review close votes" and didn't find anything, didn't think to look for those terms.

Comment: @jonsca : not sure I drummed hard enough?

Comment: @jrturton I forgot what the vote count was before you put the bounty on it, but every upvote on it counts.  I've got the question starred, we'll have to put it back through with another bounty at some point.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Well this is now done:

[image: closure filter]

In the new votes tab on your profile, you can see a list of questions you voted to close.

Comment: Visible only to ourselves, not even to mods, I assume?

Comment: @BenBrocka no ... mods can not see it

Answer (score 39):

I like this idea. I thought it would have been done, but when I checked where I thought it would be I found it was not there. I suggest this be added under the "Activity" tab of your user profile:

[image: Put it here]

Comment: Oh good, I thought I just couldn't find it. I'll update the tags to feature request then.

Comment: +1 for semi-transparent freehand.

Comment: -1 for semi transparent - that's too much effort

Comment: @slhck using Mac OS X it's no effort at all! Right below the color selector is an opacity slider :-D

Comment: I know .. just kidding :P

Comment: Whaaa? -1 for using Mac OS X

Comment: HEY @Pekka THAT'S NOT NICE! ;-)

Comment: @TheUnhandledException, no problem, not sure if adding the bounty actually _achieved_ anything, though!

Comment: @jrturton it shows the team you're serious. The team does what they feel like, but every now and again we can influence them ;-)

Answer (score 17):

Since "votes to close" are public (after the post is closed) then there should be no problem putting close votes in the activity tab in the user profile.

Comment: If this info were made available, (and I'm in favor,) it should be up to the user to decide if it's public or not.

Comment: @Moshe: I disagree; in the post that is closed, it lists the users that close it.  It's already public and in the wild.  It forces accountability for our actions.