# Statistics on ones own voting patterns

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting, data-dump

I'd love to be able to see all the questions and answers that I've voted on -- perhaps search among them.  (Or even search among all questions I've viewed before, but I don't know if that data is actually stored.)

I think there are a lot of interesting things you could do with that information, such as seeing which users or tags you vote for the most.
I'd also like to see what fraction of my votes are on questions vs on answers, how many answers I vote on when I vote, etc.

Is the above possible in theory using the creative-commons-licensed data dumps from StackOverflow?
How about in practice?  Has anyone found a way to get this data on themselves?

Comment: Thanks for the definitive answers to these questions!  I guess the only thing you could do at this point is make a greasemonkey script to record your votes for you (doesn't help you for votes that happened before you started using such a script of course).  If anyone's actually done that, do post it here as an answer!

Comment: Actually, what about crawling the site to harvest your past votes?  Totally impractical and/or abusive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That data (the votes, not necessarily the views) is obviously known to the system (because they can perform recalcs), but it is not in the data dump because it would break the anonymity of the voting system. Moreover any flexible query system would do likewise unless you were restricted querying your own votes, and *that* would allow you to peak on the Electorate badge.

I'd like to see it too, but don't expect that we will.

Answer (score 3):

Going off of **dmckee**'s answer, I believe it would be feasible to generate a "personal" data dump that held your votes along with all the other data.

Comment: Explain how it's feasible?

Comment: I presume he means feasible for the team, if they wanted to.

Comment: @dmckee: Right. I guess I should have said "explain how it could be done practically."

Answer (score 0):

The ability to see your own votes was added a while ago:

> #### Apr 2012
>
> - 2012-04-26: [New votes tab on user profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130382/), clearly you can only see your votes.
>     You can see deletions/undeletions/closures and reopens as well as up/down votes ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130380/)).

<sup>Source: [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)</sup>

You can see what posts you've voted on by going to your user and selecting the votes tab.

[image]

There is the ability to filter your votes…

[image]

…but not search, or any other type of filtering, so whilst you could see your voting patterns, it'd require a certain amount of manual labour or some skilful scripting!