# Show question close/reopen action or votes to close/reopen in activity log

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add a “voted to close” activity event somewhere on the user profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40451/add-a-voted-to-close-activity-event-somewhere-on-the-user-profile-page)

When I vote to close or reopen questions I'm doing so because I have a real interest in the question and often find myself curious about the outcome of my individual votes.  I don't have any way to track (without bookmarking) questions I've voted to close or reopen.

These votes are substantial actions -- much more than up/down votes -- and should be at least on par with leaving a comment. I'd really like to see the votes or at least the outcomes (that I played a part in closing or reopening the question) appear in my profile's activity log.

Because I think it'll come up: if I vote to close I'll leave a comment if there isn't one with a decent explanation for the vote, but if a comment already exists with this explanation (which is often the case) I won't leave one.  When reopening I feel that the justification isn't as required unless there's a debate -- and often there is, also not requiring additional commentary.  To get to the point: it's not always necessary to make comments, and so the actions can't necessarily be tracked via comments that are left on the post, and I'd hate to make extra comments just for tracking purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since "votes to close" are public (after the post is closed) then there should be no problem putting close votes in the activity tab in the user profile.