# Revisiting recording close/reopen votes in the profile

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, vote-to-close, activity-summary

Users in the past have asked about a way to display close/reopen vote activity within their profile.

I think it's handy to be able to see this information at a glance, rather than having to backtrack through the questions to find out the final outcome of the vote.  This would also come in handy to monitor voting for re-opening, etc.  As an added bonus, the entry could list one's reason for voting and the eventual closing reason, which could help in honing one's voting skills.

There were some reservations due to issues with whether these data should be public or not, etc.

[Show question close/reopen action or votes to close/reopen in activity log](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54781/show-question-close-reopen-action-or-votes-to-close-reopen-in-activity-log-close)

[Add a "voted to close" activity event somewhere on the user profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40451/add-a-voted-to-close-activity-event-somewhere-on-the-user-profile-page)

I think in this case the entries could be fashioned after those on the existing flag weight reporting page (i.e., the screen when you click on your flag weight in your profile) and provide information on the vote that was cast, and the outcome.  In a pinch, the flag weight page for +3k users could be converted into a page reporting this information, private to the user.

Of course the possibility could exist to make it a part of the "recent activity", and have the information made public as well.

I think this voting information is important to have in one place, and would make more productive and informed voters.

**Edit:**

> Okay, I get it, nobody actually cares about this.  It seems as though people have cared about it in the past, so I'm not sure what's happened.  Again, I welcome your "Our children's children's children will think this was a foolish idea, so don't bother us with it again" and/or "I like to vote and never, ever look back, Jack" answers/comments

Comment: I can't vote to close because of the bounty -- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40451/add-a-voted-to-close-activity-event-somewhere-on-the-user-profile-page

Comment: @Jon While I respect your right to vote to close, the differentiating factor is the idea of recycling the flag weight page as a voting display.  Also, I know this doesn't effect the nature of it being a possible duplicate, but it would be productive to hear arguments against the proposition.

Comment: I should note the `suggestion` "of recycling the flag weight page..."  I also regret that I didn't find your question through my initial run through.

Comment: This happened with the (re-)introduction of the votes tab - see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40451/add-a-voted-to-close-activity-event-somewhere-on-the-user-profile-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I support this idea, and I feel that putting  it in the flag weight page is an excellent idea, instead of just creating another tab.

You could also have something like the flag profiles, with the number of close-voted questions that were closed deemed "closed", while other close-voted questions not yet closed deemed "unsuccessful", the way the flags are, so it might look like this:

```
Your closing history      
 50 close votes     
 3 pending      
 45 questions closed       
 2  questions unsuccessful    
 0  disputed.
```

Moderators, please look into this question...