# Is it possible to get an Edit notification on questions that I Vote-to-close?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, vote-to-close, notifications

When a user votes to close a question (for whatever reason), it would helpful to receive a notification (in the inbox) when the question is edited (either the text, tags, if it closes then is re-opened) so that the user can then modify his or her vote if the question is properly adjusted.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40451/add-a-voted-to-close-activity-event-somewhere-on-the-user-profile-page

Comment: Too bad you can't modify your close vote.

Comment: @Jon should I close this or is this different enough as a solution or by 'activity' am I  basically saying the same thing?

Comment: It's different, but as I said, related. Also, Kop was referring to your post, not to my comment.

Answer (score 4):

You can get notifications of updates to questions that you voted to close by following them using the [follow post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/51) feature.

Comment: It's not a answer, it's a workaround. I have VtC over 3000 question until today, I dont want to follow them all :P

Comment: To be clear: it is only possible to get this edit notification if you follow the question. We are not going to put in an automated notification for this.

Comment: Hi, such comment answer me, but it fall more a status-decline imo, but you have a workaround, which is nice to have too.

Comment: @yagmoth555 Actually I think this is a better solution than getting spammed with notifications for **every** question I closevoted. This way I can only follow the ones I think might be salvageable instead of rolling the dice on whether someone will edit the hundreds of unsalvageable ones to tidy up a tag or change "it's" to "its". And I can go through my followed questions and unfollow them after some period of time if my interest in those questions wanes.