# I'd like to get a notification when a question that I've voted to close (but isn't closed yet) is edited

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, notifications

#### Requested Feature

I'd like to get a notification when a question that I've voted to close (but isn't closed yet) is edited, so I can review the changed question and retract my close vote if appropriate.

#### Workings and Rationale

Questions can be voted to be closed for a number of (custom) reasons. Those reasons are requests to the OP to adjust their question — to make them less broad, to make them on topic, to provide a test case, and so on.
The OP (or another user) may edit the question to address the issue, but the close votes remain. If another user casts the final vote, the question is closed, even though the original issue was resolved.

To prevent that, the close voters should be notified that the question was edited, so that they can review the edited question and adjust their vote accordingly.

This is for a question *in the process of being closed* only.

#### Related Feature Requests

[Notify users of a question they closed being edited or nominated for reopening](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267675/239016)
Not a duplicate, since my request is about questions *in the process of being closed*, while that request is about *questions that are already closed*. That could notify users years after they've closed the question. That seems unnecessary and we have the regular re-open process to deal with it anyway.

[Is it possible to get an Edit notification on questions that I Vote-to-close?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73341/239016)
Same request as mine, but (incorrectly, IMHO) closed as a duplicate of the former.

Answer (score 0):

If a close-worthy question is edited and made on-topic, then it is very unlikely that it will get more close votes. Existing votes will die away eventually.

But in case it does get closed later by somebody's careless vote, it will be noticed by other users and reopened eventually.