# Review close votes that I have cast

Tags: feature-request, support, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add a “voted to close” activity event somewhere on the user profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40451/add-a-voted-to-close-activity-event-somewhere-on-the-user-profile-page)

Dizzy with the newly granted power of close voting, I have found myself increasingly intolerant of poor and duplicate questions and have been enthusiastically voting to close then.

Is there any way I can review this trail of carnage, so that I can check if I've been over- or underzealous, or if any of the questions have been improved enough to now warrant answers or upvotes?