# Is it possible to see my past votes to close?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add a “voted to close” activity event somewhere on the user profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40451/add-a-voted-to-close-activity-event-somewhere-on-the-user-profile-page)

I can revisit questions that I have flagged by clicking on my Flag Weight from within my profile.

Is there a similar method for listing questions on which I cast a vote to close?

Comment: @jrturton Oops, so it is. Can we team up on the bounty? I'm happy to put up 200 for this feature! And should I delete this question or vote to close as a dupe?

Comment: I don't know if you can, I can't undo my bounty and it might not let you add a concurrent one. Try it and see! As for the question, probably delete it, again I'm not sure.

Comment: I can't add a dupe bounty, so I've voted to close my own question as a dupe!