# Why is there no list of questions you've voted to close (or delete)?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, vote-to-close, recent-activity, vote-to-delete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add a “voted to close” activity event somewhere on the user profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40451/add-a-voted-to-close-activity-event-somewhere-on-the-user-profile-page)

The activity history in my profile shows pretty much *everything* else, aside from my flag history which is only visible to me privately. It shows thinks I've edited, commented on, and even that I voted to approve/reject suggested edits. Why does it not show when I vote to close questions (or vote to delete questions/answers for 10k users)?

I don't see any reason why it *shouldn't* be shown. After all, the list of people who voted to close is made publicly visible in the question once it gets closed anyways. Even if it's only made visible to that user, would it be possible to add an option under the activity tab for "votes" that will list votes you've made to close questions and delete questions/answers?

Comment: @Random - We probably shouldn't close this as a dupe of a year old question that got no response from administration (even after a 300 point bounty was added).

Comment: Looks like 37 is the new baseline on what's on the front of the requests list http://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=requests - They just haven't gotten around to that if they ever were @jnk

Comment: So if it doesn't rank high enough they don't even look at it, but if it DOES rank high enough and they still don't like it nothing will be done?  Why the hell even allow people to put feature requests on meta in the first place?

Comment: @JNK it would be nice if they were more consistent about putting [status-planned], [status-declined], etc on feature requests.  At least then we'd know what was going on =)