# Auto flag bounties on questions with pending close votes

Tags: feature-request, flags, vote-to-close, bounties

As described in [Close votes shouldn't expire on bountied questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120675/close-votes-shouldnt-expire-on-bountied-questions/140566#140566) a vote for closure is in effect a vote for deletion some day down the road.

The issue is that when there is already a close vote on a question when the question is bountied, it is not unlikely that there will be... less than ideal user experiences for the person offering the bounty (their bounty rep will disappear completely along with any rep they got for increased visibility) and the person trying to get the bounty (wrote an answer, got +100 rep... and two weeks later, its gone).

Thus, the request: When a question has a close vote on it and there is a bounty added to the question, raise a mod flag for the mod to look at it and be aware of the situation. The mod can then consider if the bounty is an attempt to keep the question open for a bit longer (bad thing) or if it is actually a good question and the close review won't muster enough votes (good thing in that it really is a good question) in the week after the bounty expires.