# Minor UI tweak when users vote to close a bountied question

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, bounties, user-interface

A user who attempts to cast a close vote on a bountied question sees this message:

[image: This question has an open bounty and cannot be closed [x]]

That's a very discouraging, final-looking message.
The [official guidance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140566/280545) for the situation where a bountied question needs to be closed is that a moderator needs to be involved, which users accomplish by raising flags.  That would be more likely to happen if the message gave the user a hint:

> This question has an open bounty.  Please [flag for moderator attention] if you think the question should be closed.

The text [flag] could be an active link --- or not, since the regular flag menu is right nearby.

Comment: A similar suggestion, [allow vote to notify Moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121448/282094) that a bountied question should be closed, would address all of Shog9's concerns mentioned in your *[official guidance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140566/282094)* link; **and** both avoid discouraging people from raising a custom Mod flag, and encourage them to vote for closure if they had concerns. It doesn't cut the Mod out of the final decision, only reduces noise, and the disposition of the bounty is still in their hands.

Comment: That proposal, from seven years ago, requires changes to the voting logic. It's a good idea, but it seems to need development and testing resources that haven't been allocated. I'm asking to change what the message says, to remind about the availability of existing tools, because editing a message is a low-risk change to the system that might happen on a faster timescale.

Comment: The main purpose of my comment was to allow persons whom though a related idea was good (or bad) to vote on it; allowing a decision about allocating resources if it is particularly popular. Specifically addressing **your change**: A [toast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220560/can-an-android-toast-be-longer-than-toast-length-long) (which it categorically is, even served cold) has a [maximum character limit](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7ec1b871-71e5-454c-8fce-0354ef28cbbb/maximum-characters-in-toast-message?forum=wpdevelop) which you exceed. Put . after bnty

Comment: Rob, [this mock-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvK3M.png) was created on a cellphone's editor (so it's not great) but I kept all the text and 'toast pop-up' to scale with an example from the site. The first is the original text, next is a shorter version, third is the text you suggested (on **two** lines, which I am not certain is allowed), and last is what it would be like if it must fit on a single line. I hope that helps to visualize the comments above. Everything is very close to the same scale, despite being slightly off I think we get the idea.