# Can moderators see each user's Votes tab?

Tags: support, voting, profile-page, moderators

I discovered a new tab in my user profile.

[image: no, I don't care about privacy]

---

Very useful. I have always wished such an overview so that it can help me to trackback my downvotes so that I can if necessary undo them.

But I was wondering, can moderators see them for each other user?

Comment: @moguzalpenel_hak: since the introduction of the global inbox, I've never really needed the responses tab.

Comment: [Yes](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zK2AY.png)

Comment: @BalusC can you update that screenshot? I'm curious if I'm there :p

Comment: Possible duplicate of [See Who is Upvoting/ Downvoting My Question/Answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27534/see-who-is-upvoting-downvoting-my-question-answer)

Comment: @iammilind: how does that make sense?

Comment: Your Q is easy to search in Google and hence I upvoted it. Actually the accepted answer in that post answers your Q too with some extra info. It's an old Q. And IMO it's worth to mention that for the future visitors here like me.

Comment: @iammilind: current Q is about the new *Votes* tab which was introduced May 2012. The proposed duplicate has got nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, moderators cannot see this information. Waffles confirms this in a comment [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40451/add-a-voted-to-close-activity-event-somewhere-on-the-user-profile-page/130382#comment357939_130382):

> no ... mods can not see it

For privacy reasons, you can only see it for your own account.

Comment: My, how things change. Waffles is now no longer an employee, with no idea how the present system works. I am now a moderator, who can personally vouch for this claim.

Answer (score 11):

Moderators cannot see the votes history tab on any other user profile other than the moderator who is the moderator looking back in the mirror.

Comment: Sounds like a one-way mirror could complicate things.