# How to prove I didn't downvote?

Tags: support, voting, down-votes

In [Merge two mysql tables from all row in table 1, but extra row in table 2 by id column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55609631/merge-two-mysql-tables-from-all-row-in-table-1-but-extra-row-in-table-2-by-id-c/55609789?noredirect=1#comment97915637_55609789) the answerer accused me of downvoting his answer, just because I made comments that his answer doesn't really address what I think was the real intent of the question.

I actually downvote very sparingly. I only downvote answers when they're outright wrong and misleading. But since I frequently make comments (which I hope will be taken constructively), posters often assume I'm also the one who downvoted them.

Is there some way for non-moderators to tell who voted on a question or answer, so I can prove that it wasn't me? Is it in SEDE?

Comment: If the answerer is going to respond emotionally to a downvote (and sometimes it's just the ONE downvote!) then there's the chance that they won't ever accept that you didn't downvote them even if there was a way to show them. You should just ignore it most of the time, since until people perceive downvotes as aggression/hostility/etc. there's no way to help it. Sometimes, people say something like "not the downvoter, but" in hopes of having a constructive interaction with the answerer.

Comment: What I normally do is leave a comment saying that I did not down vote the answer if there is concern. If you rarely down vote you can point to the votes cast table at the bottom of the activity tab on your profile to show that it was not likely you. BTW. +1. I did not down vote your question.

Comment: You could screencap the post to show that the voting buttons stent highlighted. Especially given the community though, that would be easy to fake, which if they're inclined to not believe you, they could accuse you of. Honestly, if someone's getting so bent out of shape that you feel that you need to prove to that to them, just find a different question. Your time is too valuable to waste it on someone who's unwilling to take feedback.

Comment: Meh, you don't need to answer to him. Flag as no longer needed and let the mods handle it ;)

Comment: The real question here is why you *didn't* downvote an answer that you think is not a useful answer to the question.  If you think that the answer doesn't answer the question you really *should* have downvoted, so that other readers of the question would know that you think it's not a useful answer.  When you have valuable feedback on posts don't just refuse to share that useful information with others.

Comment: As I said, my policy is to downvote answers that give wrong information or totally miss the point of the question. In this case, it's just a small difference of opinion about the nature of the question. The trinary upvote/neutral/downvote doesn't provide for much granularity, and I use downvotes for answers that you should actively be wary of.

Comment: @servy There is no such thing as *should* or *shouldn't* when it comes to voting. Each person has their own reasons and justifications. If I vote only because my coin lands on heads or tails, then that's my right. Otherwise, votes *would* be knowable and tracked by some kind of authority—or they wouldn't even exist, because there'd be some kind of objective criteria in place that wouldn't require subjective input.

Comment: @Barmar: If one person thinks you downvoted a post when you didn't... just ignore them. Let it go; it's not worth spending time on.

Comment: @JasonBassford No, that's just false.  People *should* upvote posts they think are helpful, and they *should* downvote posts that they think aren't helpful.  We can't *force* them to, but that's what the feature is there for and what people are expected to do.  You don't have a *right* to upvote posts that you think are harmful and to downvote posts that you think are helpful just because that's how a coin landed, it's simply a matter that there's no possible mechanism for anyone to prove that you weren't in fact voting based on the usefulness of the post

Comment: That no one can prove that you did something wrong doesn't make it right, or mean you have a right to do it.  It just means the rule is unenforceable in a large majority of cases, which is unfortunate, but there's nothing we can do about that.  Additionally, users are given *wide* latitude to determine what they think is or is not useful.  Lots of people disagree on what's useful, and that's okay, but they *are* expected to vote based on how useful the post is.

Comment: Proof, if you didn't vote: Upvote and ask if they see it. Whether they reply or not downvote. Now your vote can't be changed without an edit, so they *must* fix thieir post to get the vote changed. --- Best to just ignore such accusations, they can be flagged.

Comment: @Servy That's what *you* think. Votes are completely anonymous, and nobody can or should control what somebody does with their free choice.

Comment: @JasonBassford No, that's what the site's rules say.  And yes, votes being mostly (but not entirely) anonymous are one of the factors that means that it's not often enforceable.  That you rarely get caught for breaking that rule doesn't mean you're not breaking the rules, it just means you didn't get caught.

Comment: @Servy Where is this rule you refer to? https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote says "voting down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information". The answer that I chose not to downvote doesn't meet any of those criteria, IMHO.

Comment: @Servy The rules say no such thing. Nowhere am I required to vote in any way. Further, the principle behind Stack Exchange is that it's a *democracy*. If a lot of people don't feel strongly about something, it will be reflected by a *lack* of votes. Telling people that they should vote *even if they don't feel like it* goes against that.

Comment: @Barmar Those are given as examples of the more common reasons people find a post to be not useful.  Other reasons why a post would be the opposite of "useful" would be failing to answer the question.  You can also see, "[how do I write a good answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)" for even more information on what many people consider useful answers.  You can also see more information [in the faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130046/when-should-i-vote) on what people often consider helpful, to which "answering the question" is prominently mentioned.

Comment: @Servy These are all general guidelines, not hard and fast rules. As Jason said, it's a democracy, we get to decide where to draw the line. I personally prefer to spend my time answering questions and helping others improve their answers, and voting is something I do relatively sparingly for either exceptionally good or bad posts.

Comment: @JasonBassford No, SO *isn't* a democracy.  The company and their employees make the rules, not the users.  There are many things to which the site *chooses* to let users use their discretion, for example, as mentioned, users are given wide latitude in determining what they think useful content is.  But when there is actually evidence that a user is voting based on something other than the usefulness of the post, the site can, and does, reverse the votes, and occasionally take further action.

Comment: @Barmar You are indeed not required to vote, or to do anything else on the site.  You can refrain from voting if you want to.  You're not providing useful information, but no one can *force* you to provide that information if you don't want to.  But Jason was saying something different, that people are allowed to vote contrary to their opinion of the usefulness of the post.  *That* is prohibited by the rules, and while it can't always be enforce, sometimes it can be, and is.

Comment: @Servy You make it sound like a dictatorship. The questions and answers are shaped and controlled *by the users*. That's a democracy. The owners can shut the site down if they want, and they can implement new policies, but the core principle is still that it's useful for the majority, based on their input. Just because we have laws and a police force does not mean that we don't live in a democracy.

Comment: @JasonBassford You make it sound like people in a non-democratic community have no agency at all.  That's not true.  The company creates the rules, with no authority at all to the community members.  That's not a democracy.  That people may choose to ignore those rules and do whatever they want doesn't make the society democratic.  There are plenty of non-democratic societies where people break the rules and don't get caught doing it.  Of course a community being undemocratic doesn't mean it's evil or anything.

Comment: Your voting history is documented in the Activity tab. If you want to prove that you voted or didn’t vote you can take a screenshot like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VebU7.jpg).

Comment: @Alex That's very weak evidence.  It'd be easy to edit the HTML of the page to remove or change the post of a vote before screenshotting it, for example.  A screenshot like that is worth basically just as much as you claiming you didn't vote on it.

Comment: It all depends on how great lengths you think someone will go to win such a stupid argument.

Answer (score 10):

> Is there some way for non-moderators to tell who voted on a question or answer, so I can prove that it wasn't me? Is it in the SEDE?

No, [not even ♦ moderators can see individual votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131317/295232).

The simplest way to prove it (if you insist) is to indicate that you're going to downvote it at a specified moment in the future (and later retract it) – if you would have already downvoted the post, that would be impossible.

But perhaps the best option is just to walk away? Even in the scenario I mentioned, a persistent victim could still argue you made the downvote with a sockpuppet account.

Technical details as mentioned by TheTXI in [his answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/12985/437555) to this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12984/is-there-a-way-to-see-who-voted-on-your-posts):

> To tell if, how, and who voted on a specific post, the votes are stored in a database. And of course Stack Exchange [employees/developers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90735/can-admins-see-who-downvoted-them-if-not-do-developers-with-db-access-look-it/90758#90758) do have access to that information, but it's only used in exceptional circumstances, such as investigating voting fraud.

Comment: So much for my idea that he ask a moderator if he doesn't believe me. :)

Comment: Your voting history is documented in the Activity tab. If you want to prove that you voted or didn’t vote you can take a screenshot of it like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VebU7.jpg).