# Display close votes for all users

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, vote-to-close

I think it would be beneficial to display at least the number of close votes to everyone, regardless of rep.  If not everyone, then at least the OP.  Maybe let the Close link be active like it is for 3K+ users and then have the voting controls active only for 3K+ users.

Benefits I can think of for this include:

- Would give the OP an indication that they need to modify their question a bit before it gets closed, thus helping to improve the quality of questions a bit more proactively
- Puts the close reasons a bit closer to users' eyes helping to keep them in more in mind
- Could help to control duplicates.  If someone goes to answer a question that's a dupe and they see there are close votes on it as a dupe then it's a more direct route to get to the original question which often times already has (the same or similar) answers on it.  (Yes, I know questions can be merged.)

**EDIT:**
I think the comment about downvoting is solid enough to not have everyone see the votes, but rather the OP, so I'll make that the request.

Comment: I like this for the first point - any information that helps improve question and answers has to be a good thing. There might have to be an indicating on the recent activity page though - just to make sure that the OP saw it.

Comment: Why the request has status-completed? It’s still not done - see opened [Show the reason given for a close vote before the question gets closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11183/show-the-reason-given-for-a-close-vote-before-the-question-gets-closed)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't know that *everyone* should see them, but I 100% agree that the OP (regardless of rep) should.

I'm hesitant on showing them to everyone because one anonymous close vote could very easily turn into a barrage of downvotes by those without closing powers, while that one anonymous closer could easily be wrong.

I think the OP should always be able to see the list -- and in the case of "close as duplicate," the duplicate link(s) selected. But otherwise, I think the visibility of closure status isn't really needed by those who don't have the power to act on it.

Comment: That's a good point on the downvoting.

Comment: It might also scare people away from answering. People don't like to waste their time on questions that are about to get closed.

Comment: @Robert: But that's a problem.  Putting answers on the duplicate, either duplicates an answer, or it spreads out the answers to the problem among multiple questions.

Comment: @Software Monkey - Agreed. I've come to realize that it *is* a problem and I don't do it anymore. I've removed my original comment.

Comment: @alex: Isn't it a good thing not to waste time answering a question about to get closed? Pretty annoying to put time into it just to find the question is gone and no indication there were close votes against it.

Comment: @AlexAngas I completely agree; I'd certainly be less than pleased if I answered a question that's just a vote away from being closed...