# Can the OP please be allowed to see close reasons while the close is pending?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display close votes for all users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34616/display-close-votes-for-all-users)

I think it would be useful for the OP (not everyone) to see close reasons when close votes are present on their question, regardless of the OP's reputation.

Comment: One of the best ideas I've heard on meta. +1

Comment: Dupe: [Display close votes for all users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34616/display-close-votes-for-all-users)

Comment: @squillman - not a dup... This questions asks that the OP be able to see the close votes on his/her question. The cited dup does not have that restriction. Its materially different and changes the request.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good suggestion! I think many OP's would preemptively fix their questions to address the close-reasons before the question gets closed. This would result in less people being frustrated over closed questions, and quicker reopen-votes too, IMHO.

Comment: It could also show them that their question might really be inappropriate for the site so they could close it themselves and save the mods some time. I like this idea.

Comment: @Dynamo: Good point, too.