# Why can't we see the selected reasons when there are pending close votes for a question?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, close-reasons

When users vote to close a question, the original poster can't see the selected reason why until after the question is already closed.  If they could see this information, they might be able to edit the question to make it more acceptable and averting the need to close it.

For example, the owner of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240410/why-user-instances-also-known-as-ranu-available-with-sql-server-express-edition) cannot see the reason why his question is being voted to close:

---

[image: Question with pending close votes]

Comment: You *are* prompted. There's a list of reasons that you have to choose from.

Comment: @Cody: Please see my update.

Comment: Note, this is a dupe of [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41034/), but should remain open because the original is already closed as a dupe of [another question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34616/) that is now listed as `status-completed` because the first part of the question, and only the first part, was implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by 'thread,' but I take it you mean questions? The problem is that you have to select a reason to close ('not a real question,' 'off-topic,' 'subjective and argumentative,' etc) in order to be *able* to click on the 'close' button to *use* your vote to close.

While that doesn't, necessarily, make it clear to the person that posted the question, I, personally, try to leave reasons as to why *I* close questions. Other than that the majority decision of the five (or fewer, if a diamond-mod also votes) close voters is displayed when the question is, finally, closed.

---

**Edited** with regards to the updated question:

> The owner of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240410/why-user-instances-also-known-as-ranu-available-with-sql-server-express-edition) cannot see the reason why his question is being voted to close.

That's obviously an unpleasant situation to be in, and I sympathise with that, but that's also *not* what your question asked. Or, at least, wasn't my interpretation of what your question asked.

For what it's worth, though, I *do* partially agree with you, and believe that the owner of a question, and the case of a Community Wiki question *everyone*, should be able to see **some** form of a report on the close votes accrued by a question.

But, for the record, I **also** think that people should leave comments explaining down-votes, and that's not, typically, the behaviour exhibited (at least in the tags I tend to stick to).

Comment: See my update please.

Comment: It's often discouraged to leave comments indicating you think a question should be migrated to a different site (though lots of people ignore this advice and do it anyway because it's apparently perceived as "rude" to vote to close a question), as that generally encourages the asker to post a duplicate question on the other site. The close popup already tells other 3k+ users why you've voted to close. The OP should not take any action.

Comment: @Cody, thank you for that; I hadn't been aware of that discouragement. :)

Answer (score 10):

If you can see pending close votes, you can see the reasons. By clicking on it and feigning the option of voting to close yourself, you can see what votes have already been cast. I can't see close votes on Stack Overflow, so I'll instead pick a random question from Gaming. Notice the two `1`s next to off-topic and subjective and argumentative, which indicate that there is one vote each for those reasons.

[image: Yes, it's IE8. Yes, I get boxes.]

The question author needs only 250 reputation (which your example has) in order to vote to close on one's own question, which is all you need to see this same popup.

Comment: To be fair, it's probably counterintuitive to except the OP to click on "close" when they obviously don't want to close it.

Comment: @Wooble I certainly don't deny that, but at least we do have a method. Perhaps, when there's a number of votes cast, the tooltip could be altered to explain this functionality.