# Warn new users posting answers when there are close votes on a question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close, new-users, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add an alert when answering a question that has at least a close vote as duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40316/add-an-alert-when-answering-a-question-that-has-at-least-a-close-vote-as-duplicat)

Even though [all users can see close vote counts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34616/display-close-votes-for-all-users), and close votes automatically post comments suggesting the possible duplicate, it appears that new users will sometimes answer a question anyway, regardless of whether or not they recognize there may be a possible dupe.

I think we should display a notification for them when a question may be a duplicate that they may consider checking that out first before composing an answer.

What I'd suggest is **if**:

- a question has 2 or more close-as-dupe votes
- *AND* if the user has less than 200 rep
- *AND* the user is posting an answer to this question

Then:

- display a notification (if possible, have a dynamic notification that can be triggered for anyone composing an answer that will pop up).

Something like:

> The question you are answering has been suggested to be a duplicate of <link to question with question title as text>

Or if more than one question has been proposed as a duplicate, make that a list.  Also, it probably should have another sentence on there indicating what the recommended action for them is, but I'm not sure what to put there.  Something like "Consider reviewing this question first, and if it's a duplicate, consider answering that question".  But that's kind of wordy.

Comment: I think only the OP and [other users above 250 reputation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-close-votes) can currently see close votes.

Comment: @Rober Harvey Only users who can cast votes can see when a question is being voted to be closed; the wiki page you linked reports the following: "You may also cast a close or reopen vote on your questions. With the close/reopen vote privilege, you'll be able to see (and cast) close and reopen votes on all questions." That is my experience too, as I can know a question is being voted to be closed only when the vote is to close it as duplicate because the automatic comment.