# View an Alert on Close Votes for New Users

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, privileges

### Preamble

As it stands now, the [View Close Votes Priv](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) is granted at 250 Rep.  That privilege includes the ability to cast close, open, and migration votes on your own questions.  While it makes sense to limit ***votes*** on own questions to 250+, new users should have the ability to ***view*** close votes on their own questions.

### Proposal

- Leave casting votes to close, reopen, or migrate on own questions as a 250 rep priv
- Immediately be able to ***view*** close votes on own questions as a 1 rep user
- Have a notification (that can be turned off but is on by default) which would alert the user if a close vote has been cast on their post.

Do you think this would help the new user take a look at their post and the rules more closely leading to edits for clarity and/or edits for quality?

As I was preparing to post this, a "related question" popped up from 2010: [Display close votes for all users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34616/display-close-votes-for-all-users) which is marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) however, I had a person in my office do a quick test question (which I VTC'd and she deleted after taking this screenshot):

[image: No Access to View Close Votes]

Comment: Good close-voters also leave a constructive comment explaining *why* their post may be put on hold, and *what* OP can do about it; OP gets a notification for all comments on their post. I like the idea of seeing close vote counts on your own Q when you're a low-rep user, but only *as a complement* to the close-voters' comments.

Comment: @Mat'sMug when you're chugging through the backlog of Close Votes in the queue you might forget to post a comment before clicking close.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I guess the primary purpose of this post should be noted as a problem stemming from SO's massive queue.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I'll be honest, I don't leave a comment most times. Why? Because the system is suppose to work where the question goes on hold fast, the questioner can see the reason the question was put on hold in the close vote message, and click on any links to learn more about what they did wrong and how to ask a good question. So then they would edit it and then it would be voted to reopen if it's a decent question now.

Comment: @bluet Do you think that is something that happens smoothly on SO?  How many questions sit with partial close votes (under 5)?

Comment: @bluet I'd wager at most 10% of askers *read* the whole close message, and that 10% of those actually click the link to [help/on-topic] and *read* the rulebook. Commenting yourself contributes to create a more human and welcoming atmosphere, even if at the end of the day, you're telling the OP his question is off-topic.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I'm not a good close voter and not human by your standards. I hardly ever leave a message when I vote to close.  If askers don't click links, don't spend a little bit more of *their* time to understand what this site is about I don't see why I should spend my valuable time by leaving a comment that has a great chance of being ignored, just as the rest of the help provided *in their face*.

Comment: @rene I believe the site culture differs greatly when it comes to close voting. On Code Review, we have managed to establish a friendly and welcoming atmosphere by adding comments on off-topic questions, even to users who post off-topic questions (We are still clear on why their question is off-topic). I admit, we don't have a close vote backlog on Code Review, which might be why we manage to do this.

Comment: Additionally many active users make heavy use of the AutoReview Comments script to have canned polite comments for close- (and some downvote-)reasons.

Comment: On Code Review, we have even collected [a set of tincan comments](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4952/frequently-posted-comments) that we share with each other.

Comment: I assume you want to limit the number of alerts to 1 per question (instead of 5 votes = 5 alerts? What happens or should happen with the alert when the voter retracts the vote? What happens if after the first vote (alert send), 3 users choose leave open in the close vote queue? There are tag-clean-ups which often involves close voting on very old questions (for now high-rep users). Do those users get the alert as well?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg That is good to know. That keeps the hope alive that in the future SO can become the better place on the internet that it wants to be.

Comment: @Vogel612'sShadow I find the default close reason polite enough. I see no need to add my own polite or impolite noise.

Comment: @rene Which only appears if 5 people vote to close.  Maybe the user would make modifications earlier if he/she sees it before the 5 person limit hits.

Comment: Can we get a status update on this request?  Or should I post an answer and get some upvote support (I think the Q has enough upvote support).

Answer (score 9):

Any information that helps a new user improve the site, and their future ability to contribute to the site, should be available without respect to their reputation level. I am for this proposal and I believe it to be well within the general spirit of this website.

Comment: If you are for a proposal you can simply up-vote it. If you want to share your insights or opinion, please answer (or comment if it is really short).

Comment: I am not sure how I can more clearly state my insight/opinion more clearly than I have in my answer. I am for this proposal and I believe it to be well within the general spirit of this website. More elaboration needed, such as what I believe that 'spirit' is?

Comment: In my opinion you could just have up-voted, maybe commented. There is no need to answer the question if there isn't much to share. (just to let you know: I didn't down-vote. I just want to improve your post)

Comment: @Patrick Hofman, you dashed my hopes that the down-voter had actually commented! *sigh*. Anyway I can convert this to a comment. But this just seemed such a clear answer. Perhaps that was just in my own world view. I tend to have those every now and then.

Comment: Well it is not exactly implemented. You only get a notification once the question is closed, not when a close vote is cast. Big difference there.