# Let asker see the upcoming closure directly and notify them about it

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

Some time ago you've added the funny *New Contributor* label so how about making for a change something that would be more helpful to everybody.

I'd like to suggest a feature where askers could see the upcoming closure right away, without having to click the "close" button and be notified about this fact.

I bet most users who are here for the first time don't know that there might be something hidden in the background. I think they would be able to react much quicker to it and improve their question before it gets closed. They also wouldn't be surprised a couple of hours or days later after the question got closed.

This would make life easier for everyone because currently many of us try to write comments to let the asker know what is wrong and let them fix the question while it's being voted upon. With the new feature this would be unnecessary and the asker could instantly see that the question might need to be fixed.

Comment: I’d prefer even a half measure here: a more obvious indicator to other users with close-voting privs that someone has already case a close vote. Bigger and more visible than the current *close(3)* thing. A color to the score on the Q, maybe darker as more closevotes are cast.

Comment: What do you mean by "see the upcoming closure right away"? New users are not able to see close votes on their own questions at all until they have 250 rep. In any case, this question seems like a duplicate of [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247851/323179)

Comment: @Laurel not quite, the other one is about letting low-rep users see the _close(3)_ button. This one is about showing the entire message and notifying every asker about the fact that their question might get closed and needs attention.

Comment: That question also requests that new users receive a notification on closure (bullet point 3). It doesn't make sense to have a notification without having a way to see the current close votes, IMO.

Comment: @Laurel of couse it doesn't; that's why I'm suggesting them together. As far as Close-votes are concerend is SE a very unfriendly site.

Comment: Hi, I have proposed something similiar on MSO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362087/help-new-users-understand-why-their-post-was-down-closevoted-version-2

Comment: @MEE oh, your question looks much better. I think you should have posted it here on SE meta because it's useful everywhere, not only SO.

Comment: @shiny-metal yeah, I thought it would mostly apply to SO only, because other sites don't have that much of a <s>quality</s>big-city-problem yet, ... but feel free to use some of my mockups, examples for your post if you think they are useful.