# Add close reason as a comment after Vote to Close

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I know that that duplicate questions automatically post the duplicate to the comments on the question.

Would it be possible / a good idea to have this for all vote closes?  Possibly having a check box at the bottom of the vote close window to post reason as a comment to the question might work as well.

My reasoning for this is I tend to vote close questions for lack of effort.

> unclear what you're asking - Please clarify your specific problem or
>   add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's
>   currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See
>   the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Now in some cases the question could be improved, but a lot of times questions like this are by new users who don't always return.  If I feel it can be improved I like to let these new users know that it was vote closed and why.  I copy that to the comment. example: [Google Analytics for Android: Still can't Enable Demographics and Interests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28187343/1841839)

Is this something we could consider adding?

Comment: Question is close but I would rather the comment or the notification come from me. this way I will receive a notification in the even the user does fix it. I may be able to help.   Also its an old question.  personally I think the closed reasons we have now are very clear as to the reason it was closed.

Comment: Also IMO the answer on that question really isn't an answer but a comment.

Comment: It's the same basic idea, but just with slightly different implementations.

Answer (score 3):

I got your point and I think I can go with you a long way.

I had like to propose a small update. Instead of adding a comment, why not show the message in a box **for the asker only**. Adding a comment makes it public, I am not sure I like everyone knows I voted to close (eventually, when found 'correct', I don't mind).

This is already implemented for duplicates: it shows a box telling the question is *possibly* a duplicate of another one. Let's show something similar for other close reasons (in the same *possible* wording).

Comment: I agree, that's why I liked the check box idea.  I don't always want to post this.  I also think we need some way to check that we don't end up spamming comments on this we don't need all 5 voters posting comments.

Comment: @DaImTo: You won't need a checkbox if it isn't public :) . It could say: "Some people voted to close this question since they think it is ... - this is what you can do".

Comment: True. the notification idea is a good one.

Answer (score 2):

I voted up, because I generally support the notion, but let me play devil's advocate here.

This feature request is unnecessary because the onhold-improve-reopen cycle is the intended path a bad question should go through. We have tools that allow us to inspect how improved an on-hold question is when it is edited, and vote to reopen it if necessary.

1. User posts bad question
2. Question gets put on hold by 5 drive by users
3. User reads the close reason ([image: lol]) and understands he needs to improve his question by providing more info.
4. User edits more information into his question
5. Question is automatically put on the reopen queue
6. Questions gets reopened rapidly.

This whole cycle can take minutes, and not a single comment had to be done.

Now, the problem with your suggestion is that people tend to pile on close votes. So even if OP improves his question, there's a good chance of it still being closed, especially if 2-3 people already managed to vote to close before he did.

Also, like you said, on the (vast) majority of cases, OP will never return to the site to improve his question unless an answer is posted, so the amount of effort worth putting into it is low, accordingly.

All in all, I'm in *favor* of this because it can only do good (either OP rages out faster, in which case we can stop caring sooner, or OP edits and improves his question faster, which is better for everyone).

Comment: Why the need to close it first? Maybe OP can prevent getting it closed. On some tags / sites it can be hard to get a question reopened.

Comment: @PatrickHofman The only reason it's conceived "hard" to reopen a question is because very very **very** few users ever bother improving it. In truth, even most trivial edits to closed questions often result in reopening, and a real constructive edit generally gets a question reopened very quickly.

Comment: Generally it does, but why not prevent it?

Comment: Because then you have a situation where a good (now it's good) question has 3 close votes, and blind pile-on voters might close it (even though it's good now). (Again, I want to stress out I'm playing devil's advocate here, I'm generally in favor of this FR :P)

Comment: I don't have access to admin stats.  But I have seen very few reopen requests. I cant remember a single one that I have voted to reopen.  If you think of the new user are they even aware of the fact that they could reopen the question?  Normally once I understand what they are talking about I improve it for them.  I understand your point, but think it would be better to avoid close all together.

Comment: I know, just advocating here too :) . I think closing is a 'bad experience' which we might be able to prevent with a little guidance, even when the question gets committed.

Comment: If you are advocating (Which IMO is good to have) my job as the OP is to try and prove my point. correct? please continue :)

Comment: @DaImTo Once upon a time, the concept of [on-hold] did not exist. We used to close a question, and it was closed. Because 'close' sounded so *final* (a question could still be reopened), it was renamed to [on-hold] for the first 5 days. Also, other forms of assistance was created (for example, how many of you noticed that all of the close reasons instruct the OP **exactly** what needs to be done to get his question to be reopened?). There's plenty of guidance, the question is how willing and receptive OP is without the personal spoonfeeding and care from other users.