# Can we have an option to post a selected close reason as a comment?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, vote-to-close, close-reasons

While the idea to copy a close reason to a comment [is not new](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247688/add-close-reason-as-a-comment-after-vote-to-close), I did not find a suggestion to implement it as an **optional** feature.  Let's have a check-box (or something) that can indicate that a person voting to close would like to have a copy of the selected close reason to be posted as his/her comment.  Such option would be disabled by default.

I think it will add a convenience to those that chose to use it and will cause no problems to all others.

Comment: already being discussed here as well https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300215/add-checkbox-add-comment-to-close-votes

Comment: @Dronehinge - Great. The more the merrier.