# I want an explanation of why people voted to close my legitimate financial question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

This question is a [legitimate financial question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/61906/pros-and-cons-of-alternative-inflation-measures) and concern for people advising financially like me.  I want an explanation of why people are voting to close this, outside of two personal vendettas of people who I've refuted in the past.

If clients ask why I'm using CPI over something they've read on the internet, I owe it to them to explain why and others may be able to offer input as to how they answer this question.  Why does this site allow people to vote to close something without explaining why?  I want an explanation for this, or I will build a competitor site because these are legitimate questions that people are asking.

Let's hear it.

Comment: This belongs on the site dedicated to discussing issues on Personal Finance & Money, [meta.money.se]. This site, Meta.se (aka MSE) is for discussing issues which effect *all* sites in the network. Security problems, global policy, that kind of thing. Also, I've never been to the money site, but my experience on all meta sites (particularly *this* one, whew!) is you're indescribably more likely to get what you want (in this case, the question re-opened) if you start off with humility instead of righteousness.

Comment: If your question is actually closed (note: it's not yet), it is completely appropriate to post for clarification on the site's local Meta for the site's norms for information expected in questions. If you are correct and the question is not closed, the mistaken close voters learn something; if you are wrong, you learn something. In both cases, future users with the same concern will learn something, too.

Comment: Not exactly the most endearing comment on your original question.

Comment: @apsillers Nope, clicked on that and don't see reasons at all, so that's not true.  I want to know why.  If this is for another meta, move it there.  Already tried finding it.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes (and possibly answers your question)

Comment: Downvotes are anonymous, and people don't need to explain why they downvote. Although the downvote tooltip states: "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*" so that should be a clue.

Comment: @user541852587 Ah, well; I removed that part from my comment, then. In any case, if your question is actually closed, you'll get to see the reason and revise; if it is not, then the reason obviously wasn't strong enough to attract enough votes anyway. Perhaps you'd like to [support the feature request to see reasons for close votes on your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11183/186560) so you can revise prior to closure?

Comment: Also - the downvote button has a tooltip (when you hover over it). Perhaps your question fits one or more of the issues there?

Answer (score 5):

> Why does this site allow people to vote to close something without explaining why? I want an explanation for this, or I will build a competitor site because these are legitimate questions that people are asking.

It doesn't - when users inside a community flag a post, it requires a flag reason. It then is put into a review queue for higher rep users to make sure it was closed for correct reasons. Even if the answer or question is flagged and removed, it can be reopen.

[image: Flag reasons]

Comment: Exactly -- including a reason is *central* to the close-vote system. If you have less than 3k rep, you don't get to see that reason until the question is actually closed, but you *will* get to see that reason eventually. (Or else your question never reaches the vote threshold for closure, in which case: congrats, your question didn't get closed!)

Comment: @apsillers askers at non-beta sites can see pending close votes along with respective reasons [starting with 250 rep](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes): "This privilege allows you to view and cast close and reopen votes on your own questions..."

Comment: @gnat Hm, that's exactly what I told the OP to do and he said (rightly or wrongly) couldn't see them, with 1k+ rep. Anyway, an excellent point.

Comment: @apsillers they couldn't see because they aren't used to. 3Kers see "close" link at _every_ question and often click it and after a while it starts feeling like it's obvious and can't be missed. Experience of users with lower rep is exactly opposite, they typically don't see / use it and it's sort of blind spot to them. Best way to explain is to simply refer them some demo screen shot, [like this one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XcDVF.png)