# “Vote to close” button enabled prematurely

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**

No biggie, but when closing a question as exact duplicate, entering a question ID **and then deleting it**, the following situation may occur:

http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/krudolph/stuff/sofu/close-bug.png

I have emptied the question text field but still the close button stays enabled. Clicking it will in fact result in a close vote being cast – *but apparently without dedicated duplicate question ID*. At least, that’s what happened when Jon Seigel tried it on this question. His close vote was counted but when *I* then tried to close the question as exact duplicate, the list of “master questions” was still empty.

And a the request of Jon Seigel, here's the state of the vote to close dialog on this question:

[image]
<sub>(source: [free-online.co.uk](http://www.forman.free-online.co.uk/images/missing-close-votes.png))</sub>

And here's what the question looked like as a closed question:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I tried clicking close on your question to test before I saw the last paragraph. This definitely needs fixing. +1

Comment: @Jon Seigel: Oops. I just did, too, to see what question you had given as the duplicate. Answer: **none**. Apparently your vote was registered but no question was assigned as dedicated duplicate.

Comment: Could someone please take a screenshot of the current state of the exact duplicate screen on this question so everyone can see?

Comment: @Jon - here you go http://www.forman.free-online.co.uk/images/missing-close-votes.png

Comment: Thanks, @Chris -- is there anything clickable under "Other users chose ..."?

Comment: okay, one more close vote like this, then we can see what happens

Comment: @Jon - There didn't appear to be anything clickable.

Comment: … and now we have closed the question, there’s no reason given, and the bug will never be fixed … ;-)

Comment: I added a screenshot of what the question looks like now, so we can reopen.

Comment: You broke my internetz!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real bug is that the server doesn't check if a valid id was supplied. Closing as a duplicate of nothing and closing as a duplicate of an answer should be rejected by the server.

Answer (score 2):

This is now fixed, with the recent changes to close as dupe:

[image]

1. Shows full preview of proposed duplicate in a scrollable `<div>`
2. No longer uses drop-down behavior but simpler "after pause in typing, attempt to load the question URL or ID you just entered in a preview below the input area"
3. You can click on the previously chosen duplicates below, to get an instant preview of the dupe to judge if it is actually a duplicate or not.
4. Handy search link in upper right (with improved search help page) to help you find those pesky dupes

Comment: I think my close vote with duplicate id `null` for [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1383/) was still accepted by the server. The close vote count went up, but it didn't add a "duplicate comment". I modified the client Javascript to post this vote, but even if you can't enter them over the user interface anymore, I still think the server should reject empty duplicate ids.